# In activeadmin, how to create a dialog box to display a string and with options to copy string and close the dialog box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to create a dialog box in **activeadmin** which open up on clicking an action_item. This dialog box will have a message displaying with buttons to close the box and copy the string.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: I am a beginner in rails, so i don't know where to start. i mean i know activeadmin basics and created normal pages, custom pages, etc to display and manage data as written in docs but never tried to use any dialog box. i have used alert, notice and error flash messages many times.